# Changing/removing items of Bottom bar in android

Tags: android, bottombar

I have an activity with a [BottomNavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html), I need to switch items (remove old and add new ones) of my bottomNavigationView when a button is clicked. I tried all these options but none of them is working:

```
 bottomNavigationView.getMenu().clear();
   bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setVisible(false);
   bottomNavigationView.getMenu().removeItem(0);       bottomNavigationView.removeViewInLayout(bottomNavigationView.findViewById(R.id.explore_item));
```

I tried using the [roughike bottom bar](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar) and could find a way to switch bottom bar items with a click.

I ended up implementing the worst solution : adding two BottomNavigationViews and switching their visibilty ! The problem is I need to switch bottom bar items more than once, and I cant keep adding bottomNavViews to my ui !

Any help with *switching bottom bar items on a button click* would appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe just change icon and listener instead removing and inserting items?

Comment: might be a solution yes , tried it out and it's working.
! But I need to find why none of the code of listed is working..

Comment: Accept answer please if it correct or comment it

Answer (score 19):

The only solution I found was to use

```
bottomNavigationView.getMenu().removeItem(R.id.menu_item);
```

Comment: when i did this, it then alligned the rest of the items in the middle instead of spreading them out again